# How to intercept any drawings on a Window's DC

Tags: c#, hook

I am writing a program in C#. I would like place a hook on an external Window's DC so that my function gets called whenever that window's content has changed, and I can overlay some graphics/text on top of it.
I know that this kind of hooking is possible since this is what Live Thumbnail Preview appears to do on Windows 7. Unfortunately I couldn't find any info on this subject.
Any clues, please ?

Comment: For something like this, you'd probably want to look at [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). These are the ones for forms, but i'm not sure if you are using windows forms or something different...

Comment: Can't you just use a borderless form with an invisible background that is always on top to display something?

Comment: @RenniePet DC is the Device Context.

Comment: @DylanCorriveau No, you can't use events in such a case. Sometimes the window's content gets updated outside of the WM_PAINT message handler, in which case you won't get any event at all.

Comment: @thijmen321: Well, I could use a layered window to accomplish this task and that's just fine. Still I need to get notified whenever the content of the target window has changed for whatsoever reason. Like I said in my reply to Dylan, the target window is updated outside of the WM_PAINT message handler...